# Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Heroku postgresql database

Tags: java, android, heroku, database-connection

I have created a heroku posgresql database and I am trying to connect my Android app to this database. I am using Android Studio for making the Android app. I have used the following code for creating the connection:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
}
catch(Exception e){
    //handles exception
}
```

When I execute this code I get the following error: Something unusual has occurred tot cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.

This is the driver I use: posgresql-42.2.12

The heroku database has version 12.2

Android studio has java version 1.8

I am not sure if the driver is in the classpath and I am not sure how to check this. I added the driver to the project this way: app > New > Module > Import .JAR/.AAR Package (here I selected the driver).

To check if the Driver is registered in DriverManager I used this code:

```
Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
drivers.nextElement().getClass().getName();
```

This gives: org.postgresql.Driver

To check if the Driver understandes the URL I used this code:

```
DriverManager.getDriver(dbUrl).getClass().getName();
```

This also gives org.posgresql.Driver so I think the Driver is registered to the DriverManager and should be able to connect to the database using the URL. I just really don't know why I keep getting an error when I try to connect with the database.

So why does the error occur and how can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be a malformed connection string. Are you using a proper JDBC URL (i.e. it starts with `jdbc:`) for `dbUrl`? Also [make sure you include `sslmode=require`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku#ssl).

In addition, please be aware that the database URL is managed by Heroku and will change under certain circumstances. You can read more about using Heroku Postgres from outside of Heroku [in this DevCenter article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku).

Comment: unfortunately, adding sslmode=require to the end of the url made no difference. The same error keeps appearing. the URL is formatted like this: jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?user=<username>&password=<password>